# Snowflake with regular expression

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to run the below SQL in Snowflake:

```
SELECT fm_id ,
    CASE
      WHEN regexp_instr(ASSD,'...',1) > 0
      THEN regexp_SUBSTR(ASSD,1,regexp_instr(ASSD,'...',1)-1)
      ELSE ASSD
    END ASSD
    from 
    (SELECT a.fm_id,
      listagg(a.STUID, '; ') within GROUP (
    ORDER BY a.Fm_id, a.STUID ) ASSD
     from stu_d a
     where fm_id = 1222
     group by a.fm_id
     )
```

Getting error:

> "Invalid parameter value: 0. Reason: Position must be positive"

seems it is failing at -1  or 0 value in above case statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it give you any sort of hint as to which line the problem happens on?

Comment: it gives me hint at 2 lines 1)  regexp_instr(ASSD,'...',1) > 0  2) regexp_SUBSTR(ASSD,1,regexp_instr(ASSD,'...',1)-1)  ,if any one of them fix it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table it's hard to say, but `regexp_instr()` will return 1 when the pattern is at the beginning of the string.  Then, you subtract 1, and 0 is an invalid position argument to `regexp_substr()`. [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html)

Perhaps you intended to use `SUBSTR` not `REGEX_SUBSTR()`

Comment: right but substr will work directly in oracle , but in snowflake need to use regexp_substr that is the reason it is failing , checking if we can modify the query without impacting the data.

Comment: In snowflake, either [SUBSTR(str,1,N)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/substr.html) or [LEFT(str,N)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/left.html) will do what you want